# Variadic template for creating a formatted string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to create a formatting method that with given `typename` arguments generates a string. I'm using a variadic template for this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string GetFormat()
{
    std::string ret;
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
        ret = "i";
    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(float))
        ret = "f";
    else
        ret = "n";

    return ret;
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string GetFormatVArgs()
{
   std::string ret;
   // for each arg in Args
   //     ret += GetFormat<arg>()
   return ret;
}

void main()
{
    std::string str = GetFormatVArgs<float, float, int>();
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Expected output:

```
ffi
```

How can I iterate for each `typename` and give it to `GetFormat()`?

Comment: `typeid(T) == int` is not a valid expression, `int` is a type not a value.

Comment: Thanks Captain, it was a typo while rewriting the code, it's fixed now

Comment: You are on the wrong way I believe. You have to decide if you want compile time evaluation, you should use templates. If you want run time evaluation, you do it as normal programming. Having templates and templates lists with a lot of runtime if clauses, you are really on the wrong way!

Comment: @Klaus How should I approach this by using only templates instead?

Comment: I try it actually out and prepare an answer. Give me some minutes :-)

Comment: You can implement that `GetFormat` without RTTI, via the use of template specialization.

Comment: Alejandro: OK, see my solution now. @miguel: RTTI is not available on all targets e.g.AVR. RTTI needs some resources in general if enabled. This sometimes is not the best idea if the system is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here comes a second solution, which is really straight forward and much simpler and do not use any conversations and tricks.

- No RTTI needed!
- No runtime cost at all!
- No std::string used and no other runtime functions used!

All data is initialized statical and this would be done with copy from data area in application without any cost in runtime after startup.

```
class GetChar
{
    public:
        template <typename T> static constexpr const char Get();

};  

template<>constexpr const char GetChar::Get<int>() { return 'i';}
template<>constexpr const char GetChar::Get<double>() { return 'd';}
template<>constexpr const char GetChar::Get<float>() { return 'f';}

template <typename ... ARGS>
class Format2
{       
    static const char string[sizeof...(ARGS)+1];

    public:
    constexpr static const char* GetFormat() { return string; }
};

template <typename ... ARGS>
const char Format2<ARGS...>::string[sizeof...(ARGS)+1]={GetChar::Get<ARGS>()...,'\0'};


int main()
{ 
    cout << Format2<int,double,float,int>::GetFormat() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there might actually be a simpler way to do this, but here you go:

```
void helper(std::string& out)
{}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void helper(std::string& out, T*, Ts... ts)
{
    out += GetFormat<T>();
    helper(out, ts...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::string GetFormatVArgs()
{
   std::string ret;
   helper(ret, typename std::add_pointer<Ts>::type()...);
   return ret;
}
```

I've made variadic functions before, but they always had arguments, and so could take advantage of type deduction, and I couldn't figure out a simple way to do this without type deduction. So I made the main `GetFormatVArgs` function create a variadic list of pointers which I could pass to the helper function. That way I could take advantage of type deduction. And the reason I created pointers instead of objects is because you may want to use types which can't be default constructed, or for which default construction is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes my version of the solution

```
    using namespace std;

    class END {};

    template <typename TYPE>
    class GetFormatChar
    {
    };

    template<> class GetFormatChar<int>     { char c={'i'}; };
    template<> class GetFormatChar<float>   { char c={'f'}; };
    template<> class GetFormatChar<double>  { char c={'d'}; };
    template<> class GetFormatChar<END>     { char c={'\0'}; };

    template<typename HEAD, typename ... ARGS>
    class Format_Impl: GetFormatChar<HEAD>, Format_Impl<ARGS...>
    {
    };

    template<typename HEAD>
    class Format_Impl<HEAD>: GetFormatChar<HEAD>,GetFormatChar<END>
    {
    };

    template <typename ... ARGS>
    class Format: Format_Impl<ARGS...>
    {
        public:
            constexpr char* GetFormat() { return (char*)(this); }

    };


    int main()
    {
        Format<int,double,float,int> f;
        std::cout << f.GetFormat()  << endl;
    }
```

What it do and how it works:

It simply creates a object from a class which depends on thy type of the given template parameter. Each contains only a single char. This char is initialized within each of the constructors. ( EDIT: initialzed directly in the class definition).

Because there are no other data members, the chars are ordered byte by byte after each other. This simple means we have a string. In addition we need a ending '\0' which is created with specialisation of the last template with only one parameter and here the sequence stops. Now we simply cast the own object to a string, because we know that our memory layout is "the same" as a string.

So it works with specialisation at compile time and not during run time!

Edit: No constructors needed, simply use initialization, we have c++11 :-)

In comparison to other here presented solutions it comes without any runtime cost. No string+ operations at runtime needed. The string is available directly in the memory. If the object is created static, the string will be prepared in data space without any additional cost at all.

OK, it is a bit hard at the metal coded, but it works. ( if not, give me feedback :-) )

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the simplest solution to your problem. Different from Benjamin Lindley's solution, this does not depend on type deduction, but on SFINAE instead.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 0>::type* = nullptr>
std::string GetFormatVArgs() { return typeid(T).name(); }

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) != 0>::type* = nullptr>
std::string GetFormatVArgs() { return typeid(T).name() + GetFormatVArgs<Args...>();
}
```

Comment: It does't compile with visual studio 2013, is that sizeof valid?

Comment: It seems that VC 2013 does not support SFINAE. `error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,void>'` Substitution failure is treated as an error here, a violation of the standard. The code compiles fine on GCC and clang.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like Klaus suggested but a bit simplier

```
template<typename T>
char GetFormat() { return 'n'; }

template<>
char GetFormat<int>() { return 'i'; }

template<>
char GetFormat<float>() { return 'f'; }

template <typename... Args>
std::string GetFormatVArgs()
{
    char formats[] = { GetFormat<Args>()... , '\0'};
    std::string ret(formats);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It needs a runtime executed function, which is simply not needed. Your algorithm is very expansive! Look how often std::string maybe reallocate memory! And you need a lot of additional memory. Think of using a compile time string constant and a very complex concatenated string via std::string additions.

Comment: @Klaus ouch! you are right, I modified it. what about now?

Comment: `formats` is already a c-string. You do a full copy and pack it into a instance of an additional class and return it. The copy will elided but it makes no sense for me to pack a const c-string into a std::string and do a copy in return ( which then will be elided by optimizer ). I believe it makes the things more complex and expensive.

Comment: @Klaus Right! However I need it to be a std::string, but all this feedbacks are great in order to learn :)